# Proper way to not print to shell with tee command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tee

I would like to use tee to append to multiple files, however, I don't need it to print to my shell, just the files. Outputting to /dev/null works great, as the command still appends to the files, and doesn't print to the shell:

```
echo test | tee -a file1 file2 file3 &>/dev/null
```

I was just wondering if this is the proper way to do it, as `tee --help` doesn't seem to have a parameter to not print to shell:

```
  -a, --append              append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite
  -i, --ignore-interrupts   ignore interrupt signals
  -p                        diagnose errors writing to non pipes
      --output-error[=MODE]   set behavior on write error.  See MODE below
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

I'm pretty sure this is the right way to do it, I guess I would just like some confirmation.

Comment: just use the output re direction `>> filename` at the end of the line

Answer (score 3):

Well okay then...

```
... | tee -a file1 file2 >> file3
```

Comment: This will append to `file3` as `bash`'s user instead of `tee`'s user. In this simple example, there shouldn't be a difference but it's really common to use `tee` with `sudo` to do **just** the appending (or replacing) as a different user